# Lookup deciles from one data.table in another data.table (maybe: how to take a by= argument into another filter??)

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with prices that looks like:

```
library("data.table")
Data <- data.table(id = c(1,2),
                   value = c(250, 450))
```

I have another data table with price decile distributions that looks like:

```
lookupdata <- data.table(decile = seq(0.1,1, by = 0.1),
                         value_lookup = seq(100,1000, by = 100))
```

I want to add a column to the first data.table that tells me in which price decile each id happens to be. I managed to code a loop through id that does this:

```
for(i in Data$id){
  Data[id == i, decile := min(lookupdata[Data[id == i,value] <= value_lookup, decile])]
  print(i)
}
```

But since my actual data has 23 million observations, this loop takes ages. I'm looking for an efficient `data.table` solution to this issue. All that needs to happen is something like: Lookup your value in the lookupdata, when you have found it, take the associated decile and assign it to your id.

Here is **my attempt** (feel free to ignore, I'm just looking for a solution):

```
Data[, wrong_decile := min(lookupdata[value_lookup >= Data[,value], decile]), by = id][]
```

The problem here is that the inner `Data[, value]` does not know which ID to return so I'm just taking the global minimum here. I just don't manage to get this into a `by=id` format without a loop through IDs because I don't know how to take this `by=id` argument inside another data.table within a filter. This might be my actual question but it feels like this should be much simpler then my attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a rolling join

```
Data[, decile := lookupdata[Data, decile, on = .(value_lookup = value), roll = "nearest"]][]
#    id value decile
# 1:  1   250    0.2
# 2:  2   450    0.4
```

Comment: This is powerful magic indeed... I'm starting to think I'm looking for a join tutorial...

Comment: how can I find the helpfile for join? I'd like to see the options for "roll"

Comment: 'rolling joins' and 'non-equi joins' are a couple of very powerfull data.table - tools indeed... They make life very easy sometimes :)

Comment: help on the `roll`-argument in inside the content of `?data.table`